# Update Script tag attributes on click

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am building a component that only uses client-side scripting for Office365.
It gets a few values from a list and shows them in a dropdown list, so far so good.

Then, by clicking a link, the script sets the ID and the SRC of a script tag. The script tag loads and it shows a widget from another site.

However, this only works the first time you trigger the onclick event of the link. The next time you try this, the script tag does not get updated anymore.

I've noticed that the first time jquery locats the script tag, it has a [0] array on it with the SRC and ID attribute that get update correctly.

The second time the onclick event is triggered, it does find the script tag (I guess) but the tag does not have the same [0] array and I dont see that a SRC and ID attribute get updated in the browser debugger.

Anyone know why the object is not similar on the second click, or how to get it to update the script tag on every click, not just the first?

All help appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
/* triggered on click of a link */
function OnUserSelectionMade(selection)
{
    if (!((selection == null) || (selection == undefined)))
    {         
        var WolframWidgetURL = "https://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widget.jsp?id=";
        var ScriptTagID = "WolframAlphaScript";

        var WidgetID = GetDDLSelection();

        WolframWidgetURL = WolframWidgetURL + WidgetID;
        ScriptTagID = ScriptTagID + WidgetID; 

        /* works only the first time you click */
        var aScriptTag = $('script[id*="WolframWidgetScriptTag"]');
        aScriptTag.attr("id", ScriptTagID);
        aScriptTag.attr("src", WolframWidgetURL);
    }
}

/* Gets the currently selected item in the dropdown's value */
function GetDDLSelection()
{
    var ddlWidgetSelector = $('#ddlWidgetSelector option:selected');

    return ddlWidgetSelector.val();
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    window.g_WidgetListItems = null;

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(FillDropDownList, "sp.js");

    // attach event for selecting an item from the drop down list
    $("#aWidgetSelectorLink").click(function () {
        OnUserSelectionMade(this);
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting script id with: 
`var ScriptTagID = "WolframAlphaScript";`

So the second time, this line return jquery empty object:

```
var aScriptTag = $('script[id*="WolframWidgetScriptTag"]');
```

So basically, you shouldn't modificate script ID.

You could use instead:

```
var aScriptTag = $('script[id*="Wolfram"]');
```

But i cannot understand the point of this?!

Comment: Thanks for the extra pair of eyes, I probably wouldn't ever have found the bug otherwise! The point of the code is to update the URL and ID of a script tag to pull in a widget from another site.